# React Why is my binded method being called in render?

Tags: reactjs

Here in my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.moveGroup = this.moveGroup.bind(this);
}
```

And im trying to pass this method to a custom component:

```
render() {
  return(
    <Group
      moveGroup={this.moveGroup}
    />
  )
}
```

**Why is that this automatically calls the method?**

I've tried a lot of combinations of binding and its not working. I've also read that you shouldn't bind in render, but I can't get this to work without doing that. Every blog I've read tells you to bind in the constructor

Comment: CAN you paste in you child component (Group in ur case) and its parent component?

Comment: Can you post your `Group` component, too?

Comment: I eventually figured it out on my own, but you guys were right in that the fault was with the group component, and not the way I binded things. The bindings in my post were fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In my Group's render, it was:

```
onClick={this.props.moveGroup(start, finish)}/>}
```

All I had to do was bind it:

```
onClick={() => this.props.moveGroup(start, finish)}/>}
```

edit: It seems that I was calling the method itself, so I had to bind it to a function so that it wouldn't be called automatically

Comment: It would be good to provide an explanation to why this worked for any readers that may be experiencing the same problem